# Dealing with user account(s) on devices before domain membership

Tags: active-directory

What are the best practices of dealing with accounts, admin and user, created before domain membership of the system?

- Will they be classified under an OU? Can they be merged with the domain users that will be created?
- Can the local admin users across all member devices be standardized to something like same username/password, etc?
- What are the best practices for the admin accounts necessarily created when installing OS on brand new devices?
- To what extent can local admins can use their admin privilege for things restricted by GPOs? (For example, if I restrict software installation on all devices, can they be installed when run as local admin?)

Comment: I'd make these separate questions rather than puling a bunch together, some of this is provisioning some of this is LAPS tool

Comment: @JimB, is LAPS part of RSAT?

Comment: No LAPS is a tool to handle local admin passwords http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46899

Comment: another thing to look into is applocker policies - but again needs a separation of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are talking about accounts on client workstations.

- Being local accounts, they won't make it to any AD OU. You can't merge them but you can use tools like **Forensit User Profile Wizard** to transfer everything from a local account to a domain account.
- You can't standardize existing admins, but you can create new local admin accounts to all clients and disable builtin administrator via GPO: http://www.dannyeckes.com/create-local-admin-group-policy-gpo/
- As for newly installed PCs, we set same built-in admin password (a very complex one) to all machines.
- local admins are still admins. You can try to enable **Disable Windows Installer** and **Prohibit User Installs** under Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Installer GPO, but it will only works on items that use Windows Installer.

Comment: Rather than prohibit just Windows Installers, is there no way to disable execution of any binary besides those already available on the system (i.e. made available by the admin by means of installation, etc)?

Comment: Not to local admin there isn't. A tech-savvy user with local admin rights can even bypass GPOs.  
You can however secure local administrators group as described here:
http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/windows_os_security/Securing-Local-Administrators-Group-Every-Desktop.html  
And if you need to check Admin members on all clients, use this handy script: http://briandesmond.com/blog/script-to-collect-local-administrators-membership-from-list-of-machines/

Comment: No, I don't mean restricting local admins (I'll just outright delete them after joining to domain), just computer policy to block any attempts too execute foreign binary.

Comment: In that case yes, you can enforce software restriction policies via GPO. Or even let users run only specified applications. 
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-configure-windows-to-run-only-specified-programs

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, it's perfect. I don't know exactly how tired you are, but can I bother you to answer [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/723512/170972) of mine?

Answer (score 1):

> Will they be classified under an OU? Can they be merged with the domain users that will be created?

Local accounts never get back to AD, in fact you will not be able to access anything related to the users side of GPOs when logged in as local user.  Computer-side GPO settings will still be enforced.

> Can the local admin users across all member devices be standardized to something like same username/password, etc?

This has changed a little over the past few years, you used to be able to enforce an administrator password relatively easily through GPOs, but since the update [MS14-025](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2014/05/13/ms14-025-an-update-for-group-policy-preferences.aspx). You can no longer enforce passwords without a third party shim.

> What are the best practices for the admin accounts necessarily created when installing OS on brand new devices?

In our environment we set a complex admin password, mainly for techs to resolve issues in the field. Some people disable admin account entirely and rely on AD restricted groups.

> To what extent can local admins can use their admin privilege for things restricted by GPOs? (For example, if I restrict software installation on all devices, can they be installed when run as local admin?)

Once you give someone an administrator account on a box, there is nothing they cant do (depending on their skill level).  As an admin, even though GPO's are applied that may prevent things, there is always around them if the person really wants to. Refer to [why you shouldn't run as admin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2004/06/17/157962.aspx).

Comment: The last point wasn't made in consideration of giving local admin access to anyone. But speaking of computer-specific and user-specific GPOs, do you know which takes precedence in case of conflicts?

Comment: i'm not 100% sure on this, but the computer side happens at boot and User happens at login (excluding ongoing update), so i would assume that if you set opposing policies, the User side would take precedence.  This is assuming your logging in with an AD account.  In some circumstances you may want differing policies if you log in under local account, or if you scope GPO's to specific users/groups.

Comment: Nope, definitely don't want local accounts around. In fact, I decided to just remove the local administrators using domain the control panels.