# Example user OUs and GPO enforcement

Tags: active-directory

I've never administered Active Directory before. Right now, I'm implementing it for an organization with ~20 employees or so. I've set up the AD using Samba, and everything's working fine so far (PCs can join, and I can administer using RSAT), but I'm a little lost on how to get started on user groups and their hierarchy.

Besides the original domain Administrator, can anyone detail the steps to create groups to house:

- the owner of the org, who needs to have the keys to the kingdom, and primarily the one who will add user accounts going forward (after all is implemented and live)
- administrator(s), including me, to perform all the tech supp
- and any random dept OU based on which I can divide users under marketing, operations, etc

I believe examples for creating above users and groups and enforcing their GPOs would be get started on the rest. Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**

Excuse me if I've exaggerated my incompetence, but actually, I've actually completed an MCSE (or whatever course includes AD administration) course (no certification) few years back, but since I haven't actually used any Windows Servers, I'd forgotten how to create, organize OUs and implement GPOs on them.

My question was intended to help me get started, and now that I've actually finished configuring Samba and installed RSAT, it came back to me.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - the owner of the org, who needs to have the keys to the kingdom, and primarily the one who will add user accounts going forward (after all is implemented and live)

If he only needs to add and manage users/groups on AD, use delegation to give his account this (and possibly other) rights. See [Implementing Active Directory Delegation of Administration](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Implementing-Active-Directory-Delegation-Administration.html).
If what he needs are indeed "the keys to the kingdom", no need to create a group, just add him to the Domain Admins built-in group.
Other built-in groups (ie Account Operators) may fit your needs.

> - administrator(s), including me, to perform all the tech supp

Again, Domain Admins group is the place. Should you want to secure administrator accounts, follow [this guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700835.aspx)

> - and any random dept OU based on which I can divide users under marketing, operations, etc

You will mainly need AD groups to enforce GPOs and access rights to shared folders. You should group users depending on those needs. With only 20 users to manage, I wouldn't bother about anything else. Keep it as slim as possible, i.e. create Dept OUs only if you are really going to need them.

Comment: He doesn't *need* the keys to the kingdom per se, but since all this is response to a data breach, just to give him a peace of mind in the superficial feeling of control.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question in full would mean writing a book, so I'm going to recommend two books which I read which I found helpful:

1. Windows® Group Policy Resource Kit: Windows Server® 2008 and Windows Vista® by Derek Melber.
2. Windows Server 2008 Active Directory Resource Kit by Stan Riemer (Author), Conan Kezema (Author), Mike Mulcare (Author), Byron Wright (Author).

The content of those books in terms of Active Directory is still valid on newer OS but there are obviously going to be specific things that are going to be valid for windows 2008 only.

I believe there are newer versions for 2008R2/Win7 and so forth.

Comment: I'd need to read those books if I'm to properly administer AD going forward, but is there not even some links you can recommend just to get the first few user groups going? :/

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe in superficial understanding when it comes to setting up something professional. But come to think of it, if you're only ~20 employees, if your employees turn over rate isn't huge, then not even sure it's worth even setting up a whole Active Directory base infrastructure. Not sure what big benefit you'll get out of it.

Comment: Purely GPO. Just suffered a data breach.

Comment: @Oxwivi - that could be a beneficial thing - I guess you want to lock down your machines. Then there is also a cookbook on Group Policy which would give you various recipes" for common set up issues. "Windows® Group Policy Administrators Pocket Consultant: Administrator's Pocket Consultant". I would give you web sites but short of going out and doing a google search, I don't know of any.

Comment: If you had a breach you should get a pro in.  You should get a copy of best practices for securing AD, and the 2 Pass the hash whitepapers from Microsoft.